# Flutter: How to make a StatefulWidget to reinialize State on rebuild

Tags: flutter

Although I use a Scrollvier to explain the problem this applies to other StatefulWidgets.

When building a Widget tree like this

`-StatefulWidget A
    - Some StatelessWidgets (get completely rebuild)
      -ScrollView (which is a Statefull widget)`

The ScrollView keeps its State like the scroll position when SetState in  "StatefulWidget A" is called which rebuilds the subtree.

This may be fine in many situations but is there a way that Stateful child widgets reinitialize on rebuild? Like make the ScrollView reset to its start?

Or alternatively is there a way to get informed when a StatefulWidget is rebuild so that I could reset the ScrollViews controller manually.

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/controller.html Are you looking for `ScrollController.animateTo` in order to send the controller to its start position?

Comment: I just want that it does not keep any state. I have a current workaround calling jumpTo on the controller, this should not be necessary.